# Account onLogin hook Meteor loop

Tags: javascript, authentication, meteor, hook, account

I am building an application using Meteor. I want to create a new Cart ID (to act as a cart where I can store items) each time a user logs into my application. However, every time I open a new page in the application, a new Cart ID is created. Does this mean that the application "logs in" every single time I click on a new page in the app? Here's my code:

```
    Accounts.onLogin(function(user){
            var newCartId = uuid.new()
            Meteor.users.update({_id: user.user._id}, {$set: {'profile.cartId': newCartId}})
            console.log('just created a new Cart ID at ' + Date());
    });
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is true.

Every time you open a new page you are not logged in. When the localStorage token authenticates you, similar to how a cookie does, you are logged in automatically. This hook will also run when you are logged in automatically.

Its difficult to define how a user logs in. Meteor's onLogin hook fires on any type of login Method.

You can customise when you want your hook to run, though:

```
Accounts.onLogin(function(info) {

    if(info.methodName == "createUser") {

        console.log("This user logged in by signing up");


    }else if(info.type == "password") {

        console.log("This user logged in by using his/her password");


    }else if(info.type == "resume") {

        console.log("This user logged in using a localStorage token");
    }
});
```

So here you can make the event fire only when a user logs in using his or her password. Or even when they sign up. You can use this to exclude running your hook if the user opens a new page, which uses the localStorage token to sign up.

Comment: @DariuszSikorski This can happen if you login in a slightly more unusual way. It may be worth filing a github ticket on Meteor's issue tracker: github.com/meteor/meteor with some reproducible code.

Comment: That's right, I used `accounts-facebook` to check this code.

Comment: @DariuszSikorski Even if you use `accounts-facebook` its a bit unusual for it to be undefined. I just tried this out and get a proper object for `info` with 'Login with facebook' where `info.type == "facebook"`.

Comment: info is undefined on the client

Comment: same here. info is undefined on the client. `Exception in onLogin callback: TypeError: Cannot read property 'methodName' of undefined`

Comment: @LarryW. This is as expected. There are no arguments passed on the client as per the docs http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_onloginfailure. The intent is for it to be used on the server. Consider using Tracker.autorun instead.

Comment: @Akshat How would you use autorun to reliably tell if someone has just logged in (traditionally) as opposed to have reloaded the page?

Comment: @LarryW. Simple check if Meteor.userId() is now not null from within a `Tracker.autorun` block